# Need to find corresponding endpoints for API integration of DocuSign, ideas?

Tags: api, docusignapi, endpoint

Endpoints for: 
- Download document based off unique ID
- Create new document
- Upload document
- Update existing document (e-Signature)

I can not find anything of use here (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference) or any true examples.

Comment: Answered below. If it was helpful, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your questions, I think it would be helpful to explain the basic DocuSign object model. The highest order object is the Envelope. Envelopes contain one or more documents, which have recipients (such as signers or carbon copy). These recipients, in turn, may have tabs assigned to them. For more information on the object model, [check out this guide.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/overview)

Now to answer your questions:

1) Downloading envelope documents [(here are code examples)](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-download-envelope-documents):

```
GET /envelopes/{envelope_id}/documents/{doc_id}
```

Here is the associated [reference documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get)

2) Create a new envelope containing a document [(here is a code example)](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email)

```
POST /envelopes
```

Here is the associated [reference documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create).

3) Uploading a document to an existing envelope

```
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

Here is the associated [reference documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/update).

Comment: I am entirely new to the DocuSign model so this is great for future integrations! Appreciate the in-depth answer

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. Be sure to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks